# Why is "float" a reserved word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

I just found myself writting a variable called float and Sublime Text made it blue, like it would with "document" or "window". Then I tried to write that in Chrome's console and see what it was... but it seems like, at least, it is not a global variable.

What is float in Javascript and why is it a reserved word? May it be for a possible future use?

EDIT: For those downvoting: I found it actually is a reserved word here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

EDIT2: As ES6 is adding real classes to JS, and it seems JS is looking more and more like Java, could it be possible that in the future you'd have to define a variable as `Float my_number = 1.1234;` ?

Comment: `Why is “float” a reserved word in JavaScript?` - it's not. Probably some incorrect highlighting rules in your sublime

Comment: @Andrey https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar actually it is..

Comment: Well, OK. It **was**. Because now ES5 is everywhere and ES2015 is ongoing.

Comment: @jycr753 `Future reserved keywords in older standards

The following are reserved as future keywords by older ECMAScript specifications (ECMAScript 1 till 3).`

Comment: @Andrey well it was. but I guess they still hight light it for the same reason a lot people still uses IE 8

Comment: For those downvoting: this actually is a legit question, with a simple answer. No need to downvote.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Float is NOT reserved in the current ECMAScript (4-5) or in the upcoming version (6), but was in previous specificiations.

The official reason:

> Future reserved keywords in older standards
>
> The following are reserved as future keywords by older ECMAScript specifications (ECMAScript 1 till 3).
>
> abstract -
>   boolean -
>   byte -
>   char -
>   double -
>   final - 
>   float - 
>   goto - 
>   int - 
>   long - 
>   native - 
>   short - 
>   synchronized - 
>   transient - 
>   volatile
>
> Additionally, the literals null, true, and false are reserved in ECMAScript for their normal uses.

The entire information can be read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar)

For those who still don't believe me [the float in this jsFiddle is a lie](http://jsfiddle.net/xvqh5ppk/)

```
var float = "definitively not a float";
```

Comment: Is it any different in ES6, as specified on my edition?

Comment: Just updated my answer: no, the upcoming version doesn't reserve `float` either.

Comment: @Vandervals and updated once again to prove it as well. :)

Comment: Netbeans minifier will not minify a js file which uses float - treating it as a reserved word.